# createNavigatorFactory is not a function when trying to use react tab navigation minimal example from react website

Tags: react-native

Not really sure why I am getting this error as the code is ripped from the react website docs

(getting this error after using the tab navigation code example at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation/ )

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Home from '../Screens/Home';
import Search from '../Screens/Search';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function TabNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Search} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.7.1",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using tab navigator of v5 with react-navigation v4.

You can fix this by removing the packages

```
"react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
```

And installing the V5

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.0"
```

Also better check the versions of other dependencies as well

Comment: Thank you that worked!  New to react native so will keep an eye on versioning issues.